# Hash Location on high sierra

Tags: macos, hash

I'm currently working on a project for an automated cracking tool in python and so far everything has gone well till I ran into the issue of grabbing the hashed password. Could someone tell me the location of the password hashes on MacOS High Sierra?

Comment: Might I suggest asking this question at http://superuser.com/?  Stack Overflow is strictly for programming questions.

Comment: you can `man security` on OS X

Comment: [apple.se](https://apple.stackexchange.com) or [security.se](https://security.stackexchange.com) would be even better places to ask this.